# Integer List to Double List Java 8 parallel stream

Tags: java

Not able to collect the List from Java Stream for the following code

```
public class BaseCLass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseCLass base = new BaseCLass();
        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        // Error While Assign
        List<Integer> doubleOfInt = ints.parallelStream().forEach(i -> base.doubleIt(i));
    }

    public int doubleIt(int i) {
        return i * i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not collecting. You are using `forEach`. Do what your text says :).

Comment: I need to collect the double of value in doubleOfIntList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then just collect it:

```
List<Integer> doubleOfInt = ints.parallelStream().map(i -> base.doubleIt(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But: your method `doubleIt` does not double the values but squares them

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
List<Double> doubleOfInt = ints.parallelStream().mapToDouble(i->i)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```